# Running function object in python

Tags: python, function, object, python-3.x

I understood that python functions are objects too and after defining them I stored them in a dictionary but the question is how can I run these stored functions in dictionary? And can I save these functions in a pickle file and use theme later in my codes? Is it possible? An example of storing these functions but the way of running theme... I don't know!

```
>>> def a():
    print('hello')
>>> b={'a':a}
>>> b['a']
<function a at 0x00000000033AE620>
>>> b['a'].run()
```

I need some method like `run` for thisfunction or at least view the function code!

Answer (score 4):

Just call it like you would a normal function:

```
>>> def a():
...     print('hello')
...
>>> b={'a':a}
>>> b['a']
<function a at 0x02192468>
>>> b['a']()
hello
>>>
```

`b['a']` returns the function object, so placing `(...)` after it will call it just like any other function object.

Comment: Thanks but can I store these functions in a pickle file without a problem?

Comment: Yes; they have a resource pointer, and that will always be the same instance as long as the process lives.

Comment: Use the inspect library (http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect) :).

Comment: @HamidFzM Picking functions is a tricky topic. Pickle will store only the qualified name of the function (e.g. `mylib.util.add`), and unpickling will look it up by that name. Sometimes that's a good thing, but it also has downsides (most importantly, it doesn't work in several advanced use cases). The alternatives (storing the functions's code) are even worse though.

Comment: For global functions without closures, using pickle is just fine. A string that'll allow re-importing the name is stored in the pickle, not the code.